# Cannot override Kendo Grid filter messages (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo Grid with filter message overriden (or at least I'd like to have one):

```
(...)
.Scrollable()
.Filterable(f => f.Messages(msg => msg.Clear("XXXXXXXX")))
.Sortable()
(...)
```

But after checking I can still see default message. So I tried to set it to columns:

```
(...)
column.Bound(m => m.MyProperty).Filterable(f => f.Messages(msg => msg.Clear("XXXXXXXX")))
(...)
```

And it works perfectly fine! The message is overriden to "XXXXXXXX".

The generated JavaScript contains default filter messages definitions set on every column, so it's clear that custom messages set on grid are overriden by messages, that MVC Helper set on every column.

Is there any way to set custom filter messages on grid with MVC helper? I have tens of grids with hundreds of columns, so setting custom messages on every column just to change clear button text is not considered as an option (yet).

I could create some simple script and attach it to FilterMenuOpen event but is there any simpler way? Without messing with Kendo's localization resources?

Comment: I had same problem and I guess that specify text for every column or bind to js event and changing clear buttons text are only solutions. I chose the first one.

Comment: @Andrzej - You were close, check out the answer below.

Comment: @JarosławKończak - see below.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 18 months later but in case anyone else stumbles upon this thread and needs the answer.

```
(...)
.Scrollable()
.Filterable(f => f.Messages(msg => msg.Info("XXXXXXXX")))
.Sortable()
(...)
```

The `.Info` method allows you to change the filter message for all columns.  You can also set the message via each column's `.Filterable()` method.